# fetch Ajax sent data in example.php error undefine index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax code to sent form data ajax code is working fine but I am receiving error in php page where ajax request is sent I have also used `var_dump($_POST)` and in response its showing all array values and its perfect but when I declare variable and try to get post like `$var=$_POST['something']` it says `undefined` index for all please some one sort out this problem my code is below

ajax code:

```
function register()
{
  jQuery('.help-block').html('');
  var register_for=jQuery("#register_for").val();
  var departure=jQuery("#departure").val();
  var custom_departure_date=jQuery("#custom_departure_date").val();
  var name=jQuery("#name").val();
  var email=jQuery("#email").val();
  var contact=jQuery("#contact").val();
  var passport=jQuery("#passport").val();
  var error='';

   if (register_for=="") {
    jQuery('#register_for_error').html('This Field Must Not Be Empty');
    error='yes';
  }
   if (departure=="") {
    jQuery('#departure_error').html('Please Select  Departure');
    error='yes';
  }

 
   if (name=="") {
    jQuery('#name_error').html('Please Enter Your Name');
    error='yes';
  }

  if (email=="") {
    jQuery('#email_error').html('Please Enter Your Email');
    error='yes';
  }
if (contact=="") {

  jQuery('#contact_error').html('Please Enter Your Contact');
  error='yes';

}


  if(error==''){
        jQuery.ajax({
        url:'register_process.php',
         type:'post',
          data:'register_for=' + register_for + '&departure=' + departure + '&custom_departure_date=' + custom_departure_date + '&name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&contact=' + contact +  '&passport=' + passport,
          success:function(result){
         
          jQuery('#registered_msg').html('Registration Successfull');
          jQuery('#registered_msg2').html('We will Contact You Soon For Confirmation');

         
       }


    });
      }
     
    }
```

url page:

```
<?php
include ("includes/conn.php");
?>

<?php

var_dump($_POST);

    $register_for =$_POST['register_for'];
     $departure =$_POST['departure'];
     $custom_departure_date=$_POST['custom_departure_date'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
     $contact =$_POST['contact'];
     $passport =$_POST['passport'];
    $added_on=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');


$added_on=date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$sql="insert into register(register_for,departure,departure_custom_date,name,email,contact,passport,date) values('$register_for','$departure','$custom_departure_date','$name','$email','$contact','$passport','$added_on')";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>
```

register_process.php when opened this page from inspect /network/response

````
array(0) { }
Notice: Undefined index: register_for in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_adventure\register_process.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: departure in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_adventure\register_process.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: custom_departure_date in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_adventure\register_process.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_adventure\register_process.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_adventure\register_process.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: contact in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_adventure\register_process.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: passport in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_adventure\register_process.php on line 15```
````

when all `S_POST` variables are removed keeping only `var_dump($_POST)`
network/response

```
array(7) {
  ["register_for"]=>
  string(10) "10/19/2020"
  ["departure"]=>
  string(10) "departure3"
  ["custom_departure_date"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "jklj"
  ["email"]=>
  string(7) "ljkljlk"
  ["contact"]=>
  string(7) "jjkljlk"
  ["passport"]=>
  string(7) "jkljklj"
}
```

Comment: what's the content of `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: this var is just for test to check if ajax code is working or not and it shows all array values but when i try to fetch orignal values which is sent by ajax it gives error in console network response undefine index at blablalbl

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you sent variables like that but this should help you out.

```
jQuery.ajax({
url:'register_process.php',
 type:'post',
  data:{
    register_for: register_for,
    email: email,
    departure: departure,
    custom_departure_date:custom_departure_date,
    contact:contact,
    passport:passport,
    name:name
  },
  success:function(result){
 
    jQuery('#registered_msg').html('Registration Successfull');
    jQuery('#registered_msg2').html('We will Contact You Soon For Confirmation'); 
  }
```

Read this for more information: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So if that doesn't work, I would alert those variables to make sure they have values

Comment: Thanks  there was syntax error on requested page @MD